# CSS / Javascript, How to style the cursor in an input box?

Tags: javascript, css

I've been digging through the source of [wallbase.cc](http://wallbase.cc/) trying to find out how to style the input box like that of the one on their homepage.  I'm mainly focusing on the cursor that blinks quickly, and the text that seems animated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From a quick glance at the source code, it looks like they're using a jQuery plugin called Fancy Input](http://dropthebit.com/580/fancy-input-jquery-plugin)

Comment: Bah, what fun is that :)

Comment: @AlexWayne You can always reverse engineer from their source code :)

Comment: Even more fun - try overtyping - there seems to be no end to the text box - characters just scroll off the screen.

Answer (score 2):

They aren't styling a text input at all, is the thing.  Instead, they are using a text input to trigger javascript that renders animated DOM elements.  This level of customization cannot be done with CSS alone.

If you type a bit, and then inspect the DOM you will see these elements as a sibling node to the text input:

```
<div>
    <span>t</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>s</span>
    <span>t</span>
    <span>i</span>
    <span>n</span>
    <span>g</span>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <b class="caret" style="height: 25px;">​</b>
</div>
```

As you type or delete characters, javascript is adding or removing each character as a new `<span>` element, and then placing the `<b class="caret">` element at the end, which the the animated blinking cursor.

Not that each character is a unique element, as well as the caret, they can [animated with CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions).  Transitions allow for animations of things like size and opacity, which is precisely what they are doing.

Comment: Is there something inaccurate or misleading about my answer?

Comment: No down vote from me, but maybe the slight misspelling just after the code?  :D

Comment: While I'll probably use the plugin, it's cool to see how it really works.  Perhaps I can try making my own if I want to expand upon the effects :)

Comment: @user1521753 In this case you should use the plugin. It looks pretty sweet. But how'd you like to have on a resumé that you wrote that jQuery plugin.  It's important to know know how things work.

Comment: @user1521753 also be aware of the performance - I noticed as I typed an moved the cursor through the text the rest of the page was 'shimmering' so I checked it out in chrome's timeline - there's a lot of layout/repainting going on on that screen.  It might not be all Fancy Inputs fault, but its there.

Answer (score 1):

The caret is using an animation.  Along with some inherited styles these are the two main classes for it (in a hovered state):

```
.searchmainbar .maininput:focus ~ div .caret {
    opacity: .8;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #fff;
    -webkit-animation: 0.4s 40ms caret infinite;
    animation: 0.4s 40ms caret infinite;
}

.searchmainbar .maininput:focus ~ div .caret {
    opacity: .8;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #fff;
    -webkit-animation: 0.4s 40ms caret infinite;
    animation: 0.4s 40ms caret infinite;
}

/* Character animation */
.fancyInput>div span {
    -webkit-transition: 200ms cubic-bezier(0.08, 0.6, 0.56, 1.4);
    transition: 200ms cubic-bezier(0.08, 0.6, 0.56, 1.4);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

@keyframes caret{50%{opacity:0.1;transform:scaleY(0.8)}}

<div><span>H</span><b class="caret" style="height: 25px;">&#8203​</b></div>
```

A quick way to find it in chrome is to right click on the element in the inspector and force the element into a `:focus` state.

Comment: Thanks for the Chrome tip, did not know that!